# Deep Backtesting doesn't go back further than a year?

Tags: time, range, pine-script, limit, back-testing

I am testing a strategy on the ES! 1 5-min candle.
I'm using deep backtesting and I'm a Pro member.

I'm trying to test all available data, but it will only go back roughly one year.

Tradingview says the max is 2 million candles, but there are only 57600 5-minute candles in a year (assuming 200 trading days).  Is there any way to backtest further back at the 5-minute timeframe?

Thank you

I've switched RTH and ETH and tried to adjust the date manually.

Comment: Isn't deep backtesting for Premium members only?

Comment: You're right... I am a premium member, I forgot the title.